# yum priority plugin does not allow to install package

Tags: linux, yum, package-management

I want to enable priority plugin for yum which is called `yum-plugin-priorities`.

After that I enable and install that plugin I see that plugin is working but behavior is weird.

Even I know package is exist in one of my repository yum says package is not exist.

`yum install ansible-2.2.0.0-1.el7`

```
Loaded plugins: priorities

2158 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package ansible-2.2.0.0-1.el7 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

After search I found how to fix

There are 2 fixes that solves my problem but I think I shouldn't need them.

#### First way to install package

`yum install ansible-2.2.0.0-1.el7  --disableplugin=priorities`

I don't want to  that because that can be also can create problem for later.

#### Second way to install package

Increasing repository priority from `/etc/yum.repos/xxx.repo`

```
$ sed -n -e "/^\[/h; /priority *=/{ G; s/\n/ /; s/ity=/ity = /; p }" /etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo | sort -k3n # Shows priorities of repos
priority = 11 [rhel7-server]
priority = 12 [rhel7-extras]
priority = 13 [rhel7-optional]
priority = 20 [puppetlabs-deps]
priority = 21 [puppetlabs-products]
priority = 50 [foo-rpms]     # My spesific ansible version is here and If increase priority to 10 it install my package 
priority = 99 [cmd]
priority = 99 [epel]
priority = 99 [bar-rpms]
```

Package usage explain [itself](https://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities#head-aefb31930a8f55c231768f3e9ff67177cd374f21)

> If a package is in more than one repository, it will be installed from the repository with the highest priority.

### Question

I understand that via that plugin, If I were say `yum install ansible` I could get the lower version of the package from the repository which has highest priority but why does not allow to install specific version of the package and says package is not available while it's exist?

### Another version infos:

RHEL version

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)
```

Yum version:

```
3.4.3
  Installed: rpm-4.11.3-25.el7.x86_64 at 2017-11-09 09:40


  Installed: yum-3.4.3-154.el7.noarch at 2017-11-09 09:40
```

Plugin version

```
$ yum info yum-plugin-priorities
Loaded plugins: priorities
2158 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Installed Packages
Name        : yum-plugin-priorities
Arch        : noarch
Version     : 1.1.31
Release     : 46.el7_5
```

Another debug info that shows my package is excluded:

`yum install -d3  ansible-2.2.0.0-1.el7`

```
--> ansible-2.2.0.0-1.el7.noarch from foo-rpms excluded (priority)
```

Comment: You should avoid using this yum plugin whenever possible, and solve your problem some other way.

Comment: @MichaelHampton how would they do that? Especially from a moderator a more productive piece of advice could be expected I think.

Comment: @Worp See [this mailing list thread](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2009-November/086189.html) for an extended discussion of everything that is wrong with yum priorities. As for the OP he never came back to tell us how or why he got a copy of ansible in a third party repo so I'm not sure what the best thing is for him to do. I am sure that priorities isn't it.

Comment: @michaelhampton thank you for the mailing list. It was a good read. I am glad this is now part of the comments! Thank you!